# Elastic Search remote connection from Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, remote-connection

I am having sping boot application and if i use my local elastic search i am able to connect but if i used the remote elastic search i'am not able to connect.

```
spring:
  data:
    elasticsearch:
      cluster-name: es_psc
      cluster-nodes: 100.84.57.2:9300
```

if i run in browser(http://100.84.57.2:9200/) I am able to see the details

```
{
  "name" : "i58Q9JC",
  "cluster_name" : "es_psc",
  "cluster_uuid" : "EKeTJwviQvWeTzbS1h1w4w",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.4.3",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "fe40335",
    "build_date" : "2018-10-30T23:17:19.084789Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.4.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

But I i run my spring boot application its giving below error:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{6SiLGoTHTmmiuzBTvweb3A}{100.84.57.2}{100.84.57.2:9300}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong port in your config file.  You should be using port **9200**, which is meant for rest communication.

Port **9300** is used for internal communication between Elasticsearch nodes.

Comment: I tried with 9200 port but still from spring boot getting same exception.  below is my configuration                                                                                   
spring:
  data:
    elasticsearch:
      cluster-name: es_psc
      cluster-nodes: 100.84.57.2:9200

Comment: There's not much more help I can give based on your information.  I would check that your node is still available and also check any application firewalls that may be blocking the request